# Typescript Open File Dialog to Upload File from an Angular Service without using an input element

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, file-upload

I have an Angular keystroke service that I am listening to keyboard keystrokes & performing actions based on the keystroke pressed.

I have a keyboard shortcut that I would like for it to open the file dialog, & the user should select a specific JSON file to upload, & then use this JSON data & convert to an object to use in the system.

The normal way of uploading a file is trough a HTML: `<input type="file" />`. However I am in a service and I don't need an input element, nor do I have where to put it. as I don't think a service should contain HTML.

How can I accomplish to trigger the file dialog box to open in a function & get the data of the selected JSON file that without an input and without downloading any external npm packages.

Comment: A common practice would be to dynamically add an input file field to the page and logically click it.

Comment: I don't think a service should deal with html, I would do so in a component but I want to avoid it in a service.

Comment: I don't think a service should deal with UI at all, and therefore should not be concerned with things like file dialog boxes, or keystrokes for that matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `<input type="file">` is a little bit special in HTML. You cannot generate such an event in JavaScript that would correspond clicking this input.

The only way to trigger this programmatically is to have a hidden UI component where this input is added and then the click triggered.